# jQuery scrollTop is not equal to scrollHeight at the bottom of div

Tags: jquery

I am adding components in a div dynamically. I want to load more contents why croll bar is at the end (what usually social media sites do these days). I have written following code for it:

```
$('.tabs-body-container #tbody-0 .feeds').scroll(function () {
    if (!invoked_next) {
        cont_height = $(this).get(0).scrollHeight;
        scrl_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scrl_pos / cont_height >= .70) {
            invoked_next = true;
            loadData();
        }
    }
});
```

But when I scroll down the bar and brings it to end the value of scrl_pos and cont_height have a lot of difference. The lower amount of contents I load the higher the difference in percentage. Can anybody help me find all possibilities to check and find the reason?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't they differ by the window's viewable height?

Comment: Viewable height of the div is very small. Div contains a lot of contents in it. simple height doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.scrollableDiv').on('scroll', function () {
var scrollableDivHeight = $('.scrollableDiv').height(),
    scrollTop = $('.scrollableDiv').scrollTop(),
    windowHeight = $(window).height();

if (scrollableDivHeight - (scrollTop + windowHeight) <= 100) {
    console.log(scrollableDivHeight - (scrollTop + windowHeight));
}
```

});

adding window height to scroll top worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `element.clientHeight`. This will equal `1` if you've scrolled all the way to the bottom of `element`:

```
(element.scrollTop + element.clientHeight) / element.scrollHeight
```

Or if you need sub-pixel accuracy:

```
(element.scrollTop + element.getBoundingClientRect().height) / element.scrollHeight
```

(This is normal JS code - you'll need to adapt it to jQuery if you're using that.)

Comment: I would tweak this to this formule: `element.scrollTop / (element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight)`. The `element.offsetHeight` will be the height of the contents, which you don't want. That's the same as `element.scrollHeight`, if the overflow isn't hidden. Using `element.clientHeight`, you subtract the size *on the screen* from the `element.scrollHeight`, since `element.scrollTop` will range from `0` to `element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight`. Multiply the result by 100 to have a 0%-100% range.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I might misunderstand you, but `element.offsetHeight` doesn't measure full content height - it measures the visible height - it's very similar to `clientHeight` but also includes the borders, which we don't actually want in this case, so I think you're right that `clientHeight` is slightly better in this case. I also just tested `element.getBoundingClientRect().height` and that seems to be slightly more accurate, since `element.scrollTop` can be sub-pixel and `element.clientHeight` is rounded to nearest pixel, unlike `getBoundingClientRect`.

Comment: Well, I tested it on the `<html>` of a page, so, it is possible that there are differences when applied to elements in the `<body>`.